# Sharepoint - Connect to Outlook option is missing

Tags: sharepoint-2007, outlook-2007

I have a workstation that does not have this option available in the Actions dropdown. Client integration is turned on for the site, as all other computers are able to connect this doc lib to outlook. Computer is running Office2k7. I've tried [THIS](https://sharepoint.missouri.edu/wiki/Wiki%20Pages/Connect%20to%20Outlook%20Issue.aspx) fix, but it didn't help. Has anyone else come across this, and managed to fix it?

EDIT1: It is this machine specifically, not user related.

Comment: Is it related to the computer itself or the user themselves?  If the user goes to a different computer is the choice there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, an uninstall of Outlook2k7 and reinstall did the trick.